# Python Django Livereload Module

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-livereload-server

Whenever I start the Django development server, I would get this issue
LiveReload exception: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused>

The server would still run and render my site but I cannot use the livereload module.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling django-livereload but it does not help. In addition, when I try to run this command: `python3 manage.py livereload`. It said unknown command:'livereload'

Comment: Did you install https://pypi.org/project/django-livereload-server/ and follow the instructions from this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install by using below command:

```
pip3 install django-livereload-server
```

Add `'livereload'` to INSTALLED_APPS

Add `'livereload.middleware.LiveReloadScript'` to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in settings.py file

Start the livereload server using below command:

```
python3 manage.py livereload
```

Do above things and try if it solves